# Iterating over postgres jsonb column

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

For example if I have a jsonb column without key-value pairs:
e.g.

```
SomeColumn: ["ONE","TWO","THREE"]
```

And I would like to migrate the data in the column against a migrationEnumObject e.g

```
MigrationEnumObject = {"ONE": "1", "TWO": "1", "THREE": "3"}
```

StartPoint:
`SomeColumn: ["ONE","TWO","THREE"]` desired result: `SomeColumn: ["1","2","3"]`
How would I go about this? I'm quite a beginner with the more complex sql jsonb functions, all the examples I could find relied upon having the key-value pair structure in the jsonb column to be able to utilize json.set. Since this is just an array of strings I could not find any examples over how I would migrate this data from startpoint to the desired result with an sql script, e.g. straight via dbeaver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a column named `some_column` of type jsonb in table `some_table` with value `'["ONE","TWO","THREE"]'` then you can handle array items with query:

```
select some_column->>0, some_column->>1, some_column->>2 from some_table
```

Then you can use result of this query to map new values and build new jsonb array like this:

```
select json_build_array('1', '2', '3')
```

**UPDATE**

Resulting script can be something like this:

```
select array_to_json(array_remove(array[a, b, c], null)) from (select
(case some_column->>0 when 'ONE' then '1' when 'TWO' then '2' when 'THREE' then '3' end) a,
(case some_column->>1 when 'ONE' then '1' when 'TWO' then '2' when 'THREE' then '3' end) b,
(case some_column->>2 when 'ONE' then '1' when 'TWO' then '2' when 'THREE' then '3' end) c
from some_table) as base
```

Comment: I might be misunderstanding your solution, but I'm looking for a dynamic way to alter for example 100 columns of type some_column with arbitrary strings of sort "ONE", "TWO", "THREE", so for example some columns might contain only ["ONE"], the way you described would only allow me to alter one column at a time, manually, or did I understand wrong?

Comment: Here is an example where I got it to work IF i used object structure with key value pairing, I would like to do the same for the structure mentioned above: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=ab4c31eb2c1e3599f8bffce9c5c593b0

Comment: Ok, i added to the answer a full script that should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, that is perfect!
Do you happen to know by chance if it would be difficult to convert this to an update/set instead of select?

Comment: Try this: update some_table set new_column = array_to_json(array_remove(array[
(case some_column->>0 when 'ONE' then '1' when 'TWO' then '2' when 'THREE' then '3' end), 
(case some_column->>1 when 'ONE' then '1' when 'TWO' then '2' when 'THREE' then '3' end), 
(case some_column->>2 when 'ONE' then '1' when 'TWO' then '2' when 'THREE' then '3' end)], null))